# Android "Missile Launcher" Coding - Will Not Connect

Tags: android, usb, connect, launcher

I have built and am trying to use the "Missile Launcher" app on developer.android.com to recognize my own USB device.  My USB device uses the FTDI FT232BL chip which has vendor-ID "0x0403" and product-ID "0x6001".  I put those numbers into the app's "device_filer.xml" file.  I am running this app on my Acer Iconia A100 Tablet with Android Honeycomb 3.2.

After connecting the USB cable between my tablet and my USB device and running this app, I cannot get my Tablet to recognize the USB device.  In other words, when the following command gets executed:

HashMap deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();

```
  "deviceList" shows as {}.  (Nothing is in it.)
```

When the following command gets executed:

```
  UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

  "device" is null.
```

I think I am missing something fundamental here.  Can anyone help me get my app to recognize my USB device?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a clue to my question.  I am using an Acer Iconia A100 tablet running Android 3.2.  Although that operating system allows the use of USB Host mode, this Acer tablet apparently does not.  This tablet does not apply the 5V USB bus power.  (Is there anything else that limits its use in USB Host Mode?)

So now I am trying to apply the 5B USB power myself to see if I can establish communications.

Any thoughts would be welcome.